# PHP function to reorder an array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is a sample array of all external JS files from paypal.com:

```
Array
(
    [src] => Array
        (
            [1] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/lib/min/global.js
            [2] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/tns/mid.js
            [8] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/opinionlab/oo_engine.js
            [11] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/iconix.js
            [12] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/pageBlockingUnsafeBrowsers.js
            [13] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/tns/min/bid.js
            [15] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/pp_naturalsearch.js
            [17] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/site_catalyst/pp_jscode_080706.js
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0.273
            [2] => 0.266
            [8] => 0.279
            [11] => 0.265
            [12] => 0.285
            [13] => 0.248
            [15] => 0.275
            [17] => 0.289
        )

)
```

Is there are built in function to PHP, or custom which can reorder this array to this (without being a big performance hit either):

```
Array
(
    [src] => Array
        (
            [1] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/lib/min/global.js
            [2] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/tns/mid.js
            [3] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/opinionlab/oo_engine.js
            [4] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/iconix.js
            [5] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/pageBlockingUnsafeBrowsers.js
            [6] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/tns/min/bid.js
            [7] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/pp_naturalsearch.js
            [8] => https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-590-20090814-1/js/site_catalyst/pp_jscode_080706.js
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0.273
            [2] => 0.266
            [3] => 0.279
            [4] => 0.265
            [5] => 0.285
            [6] => 0.248
            [7] => 0.275
            [8] => 0.289
        )

)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This function should work, and this is as straightforward as it can get.

```
function reindex_array($src) {
    $dest = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
           foreach ($value as $dest_val) {
               $dest[$key][] = $dest_val;
           }
        }
    }

    return $dest;
}
```

Using array_values() as suggested in [Henrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316916/php-function-to-reorder-an-array/1317000#1317000)

```
function reindex_array($src) {
    $dest = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
           $dest[$key] = array_values($value);
        }
    }

    return $dest;
}
```

This will make the array index 0-based though. If you want 1-based indexing, then use this:

```
function reindex_array($src) {
    $dest = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
           $count = 1;

           foreach ($value as $dest_val) {
               $dest[$key][$count] = $dest_val;
               $count++;
           }
        }
    }

    return $dest;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT:** I did not notice the array nesting at first, hence the following is not sufficient. As [Imran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316916/php-function-to-reorder-an-array/1316978#1316978) already incorporated my suggestion, I will not edit this any further.

---

Check the [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function, it does almost exactly what you need.

The only difference to your desired output is that it reindexes starting with zero - if you really need the index to start at one, you can `array_shift()` a dummy entry in first, and `array_unshift()` it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

if you really want each subarray to start at index 1 use this:

```
foreach($inputarray as &$a)
    $a = array_combine(range(1,count($a)),$a);
```

to start each subarray index at 0 index use this...

```
foreach($inputarray as &$a)
    $a = array_values($a);
```

---

PHP reference:
[array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)
[range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)
[array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: It might be less clear but you could also replace the call to array_values with array_merge. It can take a single array and it reorders the indices.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `array_values` function, it's very easy to use and it's just one method/function.

```
// The array
$array = array(0 => "value", 3 => "value", 8 => "value");

// Reorder the array
$array = array_values($array);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

My best shot, for the moment (quick and untested attempt)

```
$i = 1;    
foreach($src as $key=>$item) {
    if ($i != $key) {
        $src[$i] = $src[$key];
        $size[$i] = $size[$key];
        unset($src[$key]];
        unset($size[$key]];
    }
    $i++; 
}
```

But why do you need to resort the arrays? Looping trough them with [foreach ($array as $key=>$value)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) works fine in this context.